# Cannot Set Opportunity As Won

Tags: opportunity, permission-sets, opportunity-teams

I'm currently having issues with setting an old opportunity as won.

We're trying to update some old opportunities that weren't fully updated in the past. One of our users on the org is able to create new Opps and set them to won etc, but they can't set this old Opp to 'Won'. I'm system admin and I can't do it either.

Whenever we set the Opp to won and try to save the Opp we get the following error :

**"You encountered some errors when trying to save this record.
There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help."**

If any other info might be helpful this Opp used to be owned by another user before recently being changed to another.

The old Opp Owner and the new Opp Owner appear on the Opportunity team with both of their roles being set to 'Opportunity owner'.

The opportunity has been in the accepted stage for about 270 days if that helps at all.

What could be preventing us from changing the stage of this opp?

Comment: Have you set up a debug log to see if any errors appear when you try to save the opp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've finally found the problem.

For some reason the error message that Salesforce is giving isn't the real error that's actually occurring.

I looked through the logs for the specific error and it happened to be an error with our pricebooks. After fixing that everything else worked fine.

Comment: What was the error in the pricebooks?

Comment: We have some custom Apex code which handles renewals for us. The issue was that our system was raising an error because it was trying to find a similar product in a different price book (for another year) and it couldn't find a good match. As painful as it was, the only way I discovered this was by combing through the logs.